# How to add an element to an array only if a condition is fulfilled

Tags: javascript, arrays, ternary-operator, arrow-functions

There is an arrow function creating an array like:

```
const myFunction = () => ["a", "b", "c"];
```

I want to add an argument to it that must add another element if the argument is true.

Like here:

```
const myFunction = (arg) => ["a", "b", "c", arg ? "d" : null];
```

the problem with this solution is that is still adds a null element if `arg !== true` but I want to don't add anything in this case.

Comment: You don't have to do it all in one line...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use array spread. According to the value of `arg` an empty array or an array that contains `d` will be spreaded into the result array:

```js
const myFunction = (arg) => ["a", "b", "c", ...arg ? ['d'] : []];

console.log(JSON.stringify(myFunction(true))); // ["a","b","c","d"]

console.log(JSON.stringify(myFunction())); // ["a","b","c"]
```

Comment: This is pretty interesting use of the spread operator man. So, you're essentially spreading the 'return' value of the if/else statement.

Comment: note that in this case `myFunction(17)` also returns array with `'d'`, while `myFunction(0)` returns array without it. In question there was "if the argument is true", so it won't work correctly.

Comment: @pbialy - the condition in the question was `arg ? "d" : null`. In any case, the essence of the question is "how to conditionally add to an array". You can always change the condition afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `concat`:

```js
const myFunction = (arg) => ["a", "b", "c"].concat(arg ? ["d"] : []);

console.log(myFunction(true));
console.log(myFunction(false));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Array push()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_push.asp).

```js
const myFunction = (arg) => {
  const arr = ["a", "b", "c"];
  if (arg) arr.push("d");
  return arr;
};

console.log(myFunction(true));
console.log(myFunction(false));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make the function a bit longer,

- create a temporary array,
- append the element to the temporary array if required,
- and return the temporary array when done

```js
const myFunction = (arg) => {
  var tempArray = ["a", "b", "c"];
  
  if (arg) {
    tempArray.push("d");
  }
  
  return tempArray;
};

console.log(myFunction(true) + "");
console.log(myFunction(false) + "");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const myFunction = (arg) => {
  ret = ['a', 'b', 'c']
  return arg === true ? ret.concat('d') : ret;
}
```

In other solutions you have `arg ?` instead of `arg === true ?`.
If you want `myFunction` to return array with `'d'` ONLY for `arg = true`,then you shoulu use mine solution. If you want it to return `'d'` for, for example, `arg = 17`, but not to return it for `arg = 0`, then use others solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this also :

```
const myMethod = (arg) => {
   var tempArray = ["item 1", "item 2", "item 3"];

   !arg || tempArray.push("item 4");

   return tempArray;
};

console.log(myMethod(false));
console.log(myMethod(true));
```

Answer (score 0):

Ori has [the right answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52218846/2206733). Use that for all the modern browsers. If for some reason you're still stuck on an older browser -

```
["a", "b", "c"].concat(arg ? 'd' : [])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you store your array in a variable you can make it like this:

```js
const arr = ["a", "b", "c"];
const myFunction = arg => arg === true ? [...arr, "d"] : arr;

console.log(myFunction(true));
console.log(myFunction());
```